# Change file permissions for Checkpoint r80.30 so scpuser can download file

Tags: cli, checkpoint

Using checkpoint r80.30, how can I change the permissions of a file in the /var/log/ folder so that I can download it to my PC using a scpuser account? I have connected to the firewall using the scpuser account (using WinSCP) with no issue and can get to the folder but I cant download files that have **rw-rw----** rights/permissions. Below is a screengrab, the yellow highlight is the file I want to download but cant, I can successfully downloaded all the red underlined files with **rw-r--r--** permissions.

[image]

And this is the error message I get on WinSCP:

[image]

I guess I just need to change the permissions of yellow highlighted file to **rw-r--r--** but I dont know how.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to change the permissions for the file.

Using the admin account for the firewall I logged in via SSH to the CLI and got to expert mode and then put in the following command

'# chmod 664 /var/log/XXXXXXXXX_31_1_2022_13_28.info.tar.gz'

This applies a permission mask which adds read-only to the global permissions and allows the scpuser account to download the file.

In WinSCP I could then see an additional r in the Rights column and the file successfully downloaded.

[image]